# How to upgrade my new Android project to Kotlin 1.9?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio

Kotlin is now version 1.9

When I created a new project in Android Studio (Giraffe), it was still targeting Kotlin 1.8.

I change the `build.gradle` below to 1.9

```
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.9"
    }
```

But it error out stating `Unknown Kotlin JVM target: 1.9`

I check https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2023/07/kotlin-1-9-0-released/, and it mentions

> For Android Studio Giraffe (223) and Hedgehog (231), the Kotlin 1.9.0
> plugin will be included in upcoming Android Studios updates.

How would I know if I got the plugin already? How to install it if I don't have the plugin yet?

Comment: `jvmTarget` is a Java version. You want to change the *kotlin* version. Depending on your project setup it might be in places like `gradle.properties` or your main `build.gradle(.kts)`.

Comment: To change kotlin version, Go to project-level ```build.gradle``` file and change the version of plugin("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android") to 1.9.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like I can set it in the project's `build.gradle.kts`, i.e. setting it to `1.9.10`

```
plugins {
    id("com.android.application") version "8.1.0" apply false
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android") version "1.9.10" apply false
}
```

Comment: Thanks Elye, it helped fixing the issue. Thanks again

Answer (score 2):

In Android Studio:

`Settings` -> `Languages & Frameworks` -> `Kotlin`

And you can check your Kotlin version from there.

EDIT:
([See this also](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/releases.html#update-to-a-new-release))

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem comes from the typo in a documentation somewhere.
Like [here](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-compiler):
[image]

Just use `jvmTarget = "19"` instead. As the [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/gradle-compiler-options.html#attributes-specific-to-jvm) says this option meaning is "Target version of the generated JVM bytecode". So "1.9" is impossible as  Java 1.9 doesn't exist.